# Getting the significant half of a Number

Tags: javascript, ieee-754

I'm trying to break a number with value less than or equal to Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER into two 32 bit uint values.

My first thought on getting the high value was simply value >>> 32 but this first converts value into a 32b uint and thus the result is 0.

Another thought was to

```
var high = Number(BigInt(value) >> 32n);
```

however, going BigInt is relatively slow and I'd like to avoid that if possible

Then I tried Math.floor(value / 2 ** 32) which is way quicker than BigInt and seems accurate but I need a guarantee that it is accurate. Is there any chance of inaccuracy there if the value is between 2 ** 32 and Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER? It is a floating point calculation so I am suspicious.

Any other quick ways to get the high value of a 53b integer?

EDIT: If you have a REALLY fast computer, the third approach can be tested

```
for (let v = 0, high = 0; high <= 2 ** 21; high++) {
    for (let low = 0; low < 2 ** 32; low++) {
        if (Math.trunc(v++ / 2 ** 32) != high) throw "Error at " + v;
    }
}
```

On my laptop this would take 6 and half years.

Comment: Is your number guaranteed to be an integer? If it is, why wouldn't `Math.floor(value / 2 ** 32)` be safe if it's below MAX_SAFE_INTEGER?

Comment: Isn't that what MAX_SAFE_INTEGER basically means? (there is no "built in" way in JavaScript to get the high value of a 53b integer like 32b integers unless you consider `.toString`ing it and slicing that (heh)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum the number is guaranteed integer. I'm not an expert in float things but as far as I know, for the division, both sides would first be converted to double which can be expected to reliably store the 15 most significant digits whereas Number.MAX_VALUE is 16 digits so I'd expect a chance of float inaccuracy in either the conversion or the division itself

Comment: `2 ** 32` is less than `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` and so is `value`, dividing them should be safe If I understand https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF correctly. That said - I'm not an expert either and I just assumed it'd work - so let's wait for someone who is.

Comment: Googles closure library has a long constructor which divides the given value by 0x100000000 to get the high value, they must know what they are doing, right?

Comment: Re “store the 15 most significant digits”: No. JavaScript uses the IEEE-754 binary64 format. It is binary based and does not store decimal digits at all. Since it is binary, multiplying or dividing by powers of two does not change the significand, so there is no rounding error, as long as you are in the exponent range. Dividing an integer 2^32 produces a result within the exponent range (which goes down to 2^−1022), so `value / 4294967296` will compute the result with no error.

Comment: @EricPostpischil (why don't you post it as an answer?)

Comment: sounds like a good answer to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Extracting the Bits

Given that `value` is an integer not exceeding `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (2<sup>53</sup>−1) in magnitude, then the low 32 bits of the binary numeral for `value` can be obtained with:

```
value % 4294967296
```

and the high bits can be obtained with:

```
Math.trunc(value / 4294967296)
```

(4,294,967,296 is 2<sup>32</sup>. As I do not use JavaScript much, I am not expressing an opinion on the best way to write this in source code. Certainly `4294967296` is correct, but it does not connote the fact that it is 2<sup>32</sup>. `(1<<32)` might be an option.)

Note that the results obtained this way will be positive (or zero) if `value` is positive and negative if `value` is negative. If something different is wanted when `value` is negative, some adjustment must be made.

### Justification

JavaScript is an implementation of ECMAScript. For references here, I use [the 2020 specification of ECMA-262](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-262/).

The `%` operator on the `Number` type provides the `Number::remainder` operation (6.1.6, Table 2), which is specified in 6.1.6.1.6. For the cases at hand (finite dividend and divisor, with divisor non-zero):

> … the floating-point remainder *r* from a dividend *n* and a divisor *d* is defined by the mathematical relation *r* = *n* - (*d* × *q*) where *q* is an integer that is negative only if *n*/*d* is negative and positive only if *n*/*d* is positive, and whose magnitude is as large as possible without exceeding the magnitude of the true mathematical quotient of *n* and *d*. *r* is computed and rounded to the nearest representable value using IEEE 754-2019 roundTiesToEven mode.

The text about rounding is superfluous for the remainder operation. Since *r* cannot be larger in magnitude than the smaller of *n* or *d*, it is represented in the `Number` format at least as finely as each, so the `Number` format is capable of representing *r* exactly.

So `value % 4294967296` gives us the low 32 bits of `value` exactly.

In `Math.trunc(value / 4294967296)`, the division is by a power of two. In the `Number` format, `value` is represented as *f*•2<sup>*e*</sup>, for some significand *f* (here including the sign) and some exponent *e*. Then the mathematical result of `value / 4294967296` is *f*•2<sup>*e*−32</sup>. Since `value` is an integer, *e* is far from the lower exponent bound of the `Number` format (−1022), and *e*−32 is also far from it, so no underflow occurs. That means *f*•2<sup>*e*−32</sup> is exactly representable, so there is no rounding error in computing `value / 4294967296`. Then `Math.trunc` takes the integer portion of this, yielding the high bits of `value` with no error.

Comment: I have glossed over some details, like omitting description of the significand *f* (as a 53-bit fixed-point number scaled to be in [1, 2)). I could update the answer if there is interest.